# How to optionally insert middleware (multer) into new express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

In an older project, I setup a router and use multer to handle file uploads.  I am able to use multer middleware on certain routes selectively like this:

```
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest:'./tmp/'}).single('file');

router.post('/:id/foo', upload, function(req, res, next) {
    // req.file is the path to a file that can be read from tmp
    // ...
});
```

Recently, I used a yeoman generator to make node api app, and I'd like to add file uploading via multer to that, too.  But how do I do that in this new app's structure, which uses a new way to setup routes?

It's index.js file looks like this:

```
// ...
const routes = require('./routes');
//...
app.use('/', routes);
```

In routes.js it does this:

```
const Router = require('express').Router;
const router = new Router();

const user = require('./model/SomeModel/router');
//...
module.exports = router;
```

And in ./model/SomeModel/router.js, I added some routes following the pattern that was already in the file, using ...args like this:

```
// In some of these, I want to insert multer, but where?
router.route('/doSomething')
  .post((...args) => controller.doSomething(...args));

module.exports = router;
```

I think my problem is that ...args syntax.  How do I get multer inserted into the chain of middleware with the args?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mount middleware on specific routers:

```
router.use(upload) // runs for all routes mounted under this call
router.route('/doSomething')
  .post((...args) => controller.doSomething(...args));

module.exports = router;
```

You should also be able to put it before your post callback:

```
router.route('/doSomething')
  .post(upload, (...args) => controller.doSomething(...args));
```

Comment: The first idea, using `use` causes an error, saying `router.route(...).use is not a function`, But the second idea, passing it to the post works great.  Thanks very much!